# JQUERY change text or value of child element in parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I make some code width jquery My goal is add lists under the #pivot and above `<li><a href="#">bottom</a></li>`  How to do??

When I tried like this the only `<li><a href="#"></a></li>` added without text "new row"

Please teach me

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#">top</a></li>
<li id="pivot"><a href="#">Pivot</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">bottom</a></li>
```

**Javascript**

```
var dom = '<li><a href="#"></a></li>';
$('a',dom).text('new row');
$('#pivot').after(dom);
```

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: As I said only <li><a href="#"></a></li> added between #pivot and bottom without text "new row"

Comment: The addresses were the downvoters not you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are creating a jQuery object from a string but you don't store/use the created elements.

```
$(dom) // parse the string and create a jQuery object
   .find('a') // find the `a` descendants 
   .text('new row') // update their textContent
   .end() // get the previous jQuery collection
   .insertAfter('#pivot'); // insert the collection after `#pivot` element
```

Comment: it doesn`t work I added console.log(dom) at the bottom of your code and the the dom has only <li><a href="#"></a></li> it was not change

Comment: @the1900 It works for me, i.e. it does what it should http://jsfiddle.net/mzbydw53/. `dom` is a string. `$(dom)` parses the string and creates the elements but doesn't change the `dom` string. There is a difference between DOM! elements and a string. If you want to get the string representation of the element use the `outerHTML` property. `dom =  $(dom).find('a').text('new row').end().prop('outerHTML')`.

Comment: I`m using chrome 39.x obviously at the console it does not show me "new row" I just copied your code and add  console.log(dom) at the end of code then it show only <li><a href="#"></a></li>

Answer (score 1):

`dom` is not a live node. It is just string..

If you create a jquery object out of it first, it will work

```
var dom = $('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
$('a',dom).text('new row');
$('#pivot').after(dom);
```

Comment: @the1900 the initial string is wrapped in wrapped in `$()` which means we create a jQuery object and store that in the `dom` variable.